# Kestrel failed to start UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kestrel-http-server

I have the folowing config:

[Unit]
    Description=Example .NET Web API Application running on CentOS 7

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/FEEDER
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/FEEDER/FeedService.MVC.dll
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when I start the prgram I dont get any error.

the status throw this:

```
 sudo ystemctl status kestrel-hellomvc.service
    ● kestrel-hellomvc.service - Example .NET Web API Application running on CentOS 7
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-hellomvc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ג' 2017-10-31 09:26:20 IST; 54min ago
     Main PID: 20077 (code=exited, status=131/n/a)

    אוק 31 09:26:20 avi-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped Example .NET Web API Application running on CentOS 7.
    אוק 31 09:26:20 avi-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Example .NET Web API Application running on CentOS 7.
    אוק 31 09:26:20 avi-VirtualBox systemd[1]: kestrel-hellomvc.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=131/n/a
    אוק 31 09:26:20 avi-VirtualBox systemd[1]: kestrel-hellomvc.service: Unit entered failed state.
    אוק 31 09:26:20 avi-VirtualBox systemd[1]: kestrel-hellomvc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Warning: kestrel-hellomvc.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

the owner of the folder is `www-data` and the permissions are 0755

What might be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should deploy your app *myapp* with:

```
sudo cp -a /home/user/myapp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/* /var/aspnetcore/myapp
```

eg. 
Copy all files from build folder to deployment location (*.json etc)